# What is the relation between an inventory and an item called?

Tags: terminology

I have the following problem in postgres. I'm trying to create an inventory system. There are item types that can be created procedurally ("apple","sword","gold")  stored in item_type and inventories stored in inventory. In some cases an item type with additional information may inherit item_type. I could just create an instance of item_type for each item within an inventory, but that causes some problem with inheritance.
I have decided to create a new relation that describes an item being in an inventory, which only stores the item_type id, the inventory id and the amount of that item.
Whats the term for such a relation? Basically for an item being inside a collection?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow, but I think you are describing an N:M relationship (said as: "N to M relationship"). N:M relationships can have additional metadata which is where you may be able to store the number of each item in each inventory.

Comment: yes it would be M:N. Just looking for the right term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

- inventory_assignment
- inventory_mapping
- [inventory_]stock (as you are also saving the count, it seems)